# Cannot read property of undefined while checking for undefined

Tags: node.js, undefined, typeof

I'm having some issues managing 'undefined' in Node v10

Considering the following object:

```
const dictionary = {
    weeklyContest: {
        victorySubject: {
            en: 'Congratulations, you are this week\'s lucky winner!',
            fr: 'Félicitations, vous êtes l\'heureux gagnant de cette semaine!',
            de: 'Herzlichen Glückwunsch, Sie sind der glückliche Gewinner dieser Woche!',
            es: '¡Felicidades, eres el afortunado ganador de esta semana!',
            ru: 'Поздравляем, вы счастливый обладатель этой недели!',
            default: 'Congratulations, you are this week\'s lucky winner!'
        }
    },
    default: {
        victorySubject: {
            en: 'Congratulations, you are today\'s lucky winner!',
            default: 'Congratulations, you are today\'s lucky winner!'
        }
    }
};
```

and the following piece of code:

```
let contestSlug = 'nonExistingContest';
let stringName = 'victorySubject';
let stringLocale = 'fr';
let contestProp = (typeof(dictionary[contestSlug]) === 'undefined' || typeof(dictionary[contestSlug][stringName]) === 'undefined') ? 'default' : contestSlug;
let localeProp = (typeof(dictionary[contestProp][stringName][stringLocale]) === 'undefined') ? 'default' : stringLocale;
```

`contestProp` gets correctly assigned with `'default'` cause there is no first-level property called `'nonExistingContest'`, making the second type check on line 5 become:

```
let localeProp = (typeof(dictionary['default']['victorySubject']['fr']) === 'undefined') ? 'default' : stringLocale;
```

Now, considering I had a debug console attached and considering this debug result:

```
contestProp
> 'default'

stringName
> 'victorySubject'

stringLocale
> 'fr'

typeof(dictionary[contestProp][stringName][stringLocale]) === 'undefined'
> true

typeof(dictionary['default']['victorySubject']['fr']) === 'undefined'
> true
```

I don't understand why the assignment for localeProp on line 5 returns the error:

```
Cannot read property 'victorySubject' of undefined
```

Despite I actually just want to check for undefined.
I already checked similar questions and they all suggest alternative implementations, but I would really like to understand the behaviour that leads to the error.
Any ideas? Thanks in advance for your time!

Comment: It is because. You are comparing `dictionary['default']['victorySubject']['fr']`. So it will never reach to `fr` as  `default` might not have have data. So you are checking `dictionary['default']['victorySubject']['fr']` to be undefined but what happen `dictionary` is undefined. So that's why its giving that error(it never reach to end of string it breaks before :-))

Comment: @ShubhamVerma what do you mean by "might not have data"? Either it has or it hasn't and, it this case, `dictionary['default']` has data and `dictionary['default']['victorySubject']` has data too.

Comment: If that is the case you wont have this error `Cannot read property 'victorySubject' of undefined` . Here is the demo if value is static: https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-feynman-rfhki?file=/src/index.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by creating a middle variable each time with the partial object I need to compare:

**OLD**

```
let contestProp = (typeof(dictionary[contestSlug]) === 'undefined' || typeof(dictionary[contestSlug][stringName]) === 'undefined') ? 'default' : contestSlug;
let localeProp = (typeof(contestStrings) === 'undefined' || typeof(contestStrings[stringLocale]) === 'undefined') ? 'default' : stringLocale;
```

**NEW**

```
let contestProp = (typeof(dictionary[contestSlug]) === 'undefined') ? 'default' : contestSlug;
let partialDictionary = dictionary[contestProp];
contestProp = (typeof(partialDictionary[stringName]) === 'undefined') ? 'default' : contestSlug;
partialDictionary = dictionary[contestProp][stringName];
let localeProp = (typeof(partialDictionary) === 'undefined' || typeof(partialDictionary[stringLocale]) === 'undefined') ? 'default' : stringLocale;
```

I still I don't follow the logic leading to the error. I will wait a bit for some ideas before accepting this answer.